# Is the a way to get the logs from Mailgun to understand why it's not submitting on my Heroku website?

Tags: heroku

I'am working on AWS Cloud9 developing a website.  I have transferred my Ruby on Rails App from Cloud9 to Heroku servers.  I received a Heroku domain and choose to add on the Mailgun Service.  I have signed up to Mailgun and I've tried to test the service.  Everytime I click the submit button on my website, I receive the message, "We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

This is problem starting on the Heroku side? or the Mailgun side?  I've used the recommended ports.